# Why does AWS Lambda Node.js example include javascript objects with keys like "S:" and "N:"?

Tags: javascript, json, node.js, amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb

While browsing through [this AWS tutorial](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/sdk-for-javascript/v2/developer-guide/nodejs-write-lambda-function-example.html), I noticed this code example:

```
// define JSON used to format Lambda function response
var slotResults = {
  'isWinner' : false,
  'leftWheelImage' : {'file' : {S: ''}},
  'middleWheelImage' : {'file' : {S: ''}},
  'rightWheelImage' : {'file' : {S: ''}}
};

// define JSON for making getItem calls to the slotWheels DynamoDB table    
var thisPullParams = {
    Key : {'slotPosition' : {N: ''}},
    TableName: 'slotWheels',
    ProjectionExpression: 'imageFile'
};
```

Later, these objects are used in ways like this:

```
  // assign resolved promise values to returned JSON
  slotResults.leftWheelImage.file.S = values[0];
```

It looks like the "S:" and "N:" are being used to denote the type of the following value. Why is this being done? Does this convention have a name and sort of definition?

Answer (score 0):

Found my answer... These are [DynamoDB data type descriptors](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/amazondynamodb/latest/developerguide/Programming.LowLevelAPI.html#Programming.LowLevelAPI.DataTypeDescriptors). They are metadata that must be included when using the low-level Dynamo API. It's confusing in the example because no passing of slotResults to Dynamo is shown. They must have followed the Dynamo convention for stylistic consistency.

Comment: I don't think they are just following that convention for stylistic consistency. They are actually using DynamoDB in that example, and they would need to construct the objects that way if they plan to insert them into DynamoDB.